# React Router hierarchy with rendering components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm passing an object to a class component and want to have that component open in a different route. The routing works, but all the time the props are undefined in the child component unless I move the <Route path=''...> line before every other component. The props work, but the page display is not correct.

PARENT

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./Header";
import DarbaiLT from "./DarbaiLT";
import AnObject from "./AnObject";

let clickeddiv = ''

class App extends Component {
   onObjectClick = (clickeddivffromdarbai) => {
    clickeddiv =  clickeddivffromdarbai;
    console.log("clickeddiv: ", clickeddiv);
  };

    *//clickeddiv is data coming from DarbaiLT component*
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/object/:id" exact component={AnObject} />
            <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
            <Route path="/contacts" exact component={Contacts} />
            <Route path="/partners" exact component={Partneriai} />
            <DarbaiLT onObjectClick={this.onObjectClick} />
            <AnObject dataforComponent={clickeddiv}/>     //when this line is the last, it's not working
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

CHILD

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class AnObject extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div onClick={() => console.log(this.props.dataforComponent)}>
          <img src='../smth/pic.jpg' width="100%" />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default AnObject;
```

if I move the  line to the top, passing of props works, but then all pages show only the AnObject, and doesn't render the About, Contacts and so on...

```
 <Router>
        
        <div>
          
          <Header />
          <Slides />
          <Switch> 
            <AnObject stateforyou={clickeddiv}/>         //if the line is here, routing doesn't work
            <Route path="/object/:id" exact component={AnObject} />
            <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
            <Route path="/contacts" exact component={Contacts} />
            <Route path="/partners" exact component={Partneriai} />
            <DarbaiLT onObjectClick={this.onObjectClick} />
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the documentation of React Router states that: "All children of a < Switch > should be < Route >". 
Using the react-router Switch is like using switch case statement of javascript, whenever the link is matched to the route, the passed component gets rendered. Your problem here, however, is how to pass props to the rendered component which is done this way:

```
      <Switch> 
        <Route path="/object/:id" exact component={() => <AnObject stateforyou={clickeddiv}/> } />
        <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
        <Route path="/contacts" exact component={Contacts} />
        <Route path="/partners" exact component={Partneriai} />
      </Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand the issue. But when you use `<Switch>` in the react-router, it will render only the first match.

You have a switch set up like this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
    <DarbaiLT onObjectClick={this.onObjectClick} />
    <AnObject dataforComponent={clickeddiv}/>
</Switch>
```

This means that if the visitor is at the url `/about`, it will render only the `About` component and nothing else. If you want to be able to render multiple components simultaneously as siblings, remove the `<Switch>...</Switch>`.